# Windows Phone Store: Same App Name

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-store

I'm currently trying publish my app in the windows phone store. The thing is that I want to have a specific name, let's say 'Notes'. So in the store it should have the title 'Notes', but there's already another app (from another publisher) named 'Notes'.
How do I upload my App with the name 'Notes' when there's already another app with the same name?

See these both apps as an example (both have the same name, but they're from another publisher):
http://www.windowsphone.com/de-de/store/app/note-it/78a0f2dd-e988-42b4-94ff-6dd62ed18146
http://www.windowsphone.com/de-de/store/app/note-it/964e7994-0575-4770-b393-b471e74a45b4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In past you could have set same app name for two different apps. But last year Microsoft changed it's policy and started reserving the app names. Now, no new app can have use already existing/reserved name.

Comment: Read something similiar like this, too (they've changed it due to universal apps). Microsoft should note this somewhere, else it's confusing to see other apps with the same name while you can't submit an app with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it is written in Microsoft's website.

> **Note**: If this name you entered is already reserved or in use by another developer, you'll see an error message and won't be able to reserve that name. If you are unable to reserve a name for which you hold the trademark or other legal right, or you see another app in the Windows Store using that name, [contact Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/info/cpyrtInfrg.aspx).

So you cannot use a name for your app, if an other app with that same name is already present in the store.

Comment: and how are there 2 apps with the same name in the store (see the links given above)?

Comment: The unique name requirement was first added to the Windows 8 Store, and then when they merged with the Windows Phone Store, the requirement was added for phone apps as well. Before that, it was possible to submit an app with the same name as another, and Microsoft couldn't just remove those with duplicate names, so they stayed. Hope that helps clarify things. :)